# iPhone Animated Loading Screen

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there a way to have an animated loading screen for my iPhone application as opposed to the Default.png that I currently am using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short - no. The purpose of the Default.png is to give the iPhone OS something to display to the user while it loads your application in. The best you can do is to speed up the initial load of your application (say defer your resource loading until after the program is running), then add your own animation while you actually load your resources 'behind the scenes'.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of.  It kind of makes sense though.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of it as an animated loading screen then no, but having the first view of you application load all the data and do something while it is doing that then surely yes, but I am trying to do that and am failing at the moment

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, unfortunately not.  The point of the lightness of default.png is to allow the app to do intensive ramp-up behind the scenes.  Animation would eat precious CPU cycles.

However, if you need to do more processing once your app has launched - you could do a threaded CAnimation during this time.

Answer (score 0):

no, but if your initialization take lengthy time.
you can add an customized animating launching view once the application is launched.

for short.
after launched, before all the real initialization, alloc, init and display a view which is exactly the same as default.png but with animating effect.

while that animating view is displaying, init the real stuffs of your application in background
replace the animating view while done

Answer (score 0):

You can do what one of the app which I know does. They have created series of images, which when displayed in sequence will make one believe that the splash screen is animating. You can check this app to get an idea: TravellerID

Hope this helps.